# get values between two dates in silverstripe

Tags: sql, silverstripe, datefield

i have added two date fields. i want to retrieve the data between those two  table.PaymentDate and ChequePostedDate are two fields. so i need to get the rows between two dates.

simply search content have two date fields. i want to retrieve the rows(data) between those two dates

```
public function __construct($modelClass, $fields = null, $filters = null) {

    $fields = new FieldList(array(

        DateField::create('PaymentDate','Payment Date : from')
            ->setConfig('dateformat', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
            ->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
            ->setAttribute('placeholder','YYYY-MM-DD')
            ->setDescription(sprintf(
                _t('FormField.Example', 'e.g. %s', 'Example format'),
                Convert::raw2xml(Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))
            )),
        DateField::create('ChequePostedDate','cr Date : to')
            ->setConfig('dateformat', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
            ->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
            ->setAttribute('placeholder','YYYY-MM-DD')
            ->setDescription(sprintf(
                _t('FormField.Example', 'e.g. %s', 'Example format'),
                Convert::raw2xml(Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))
            )),

        ));

    $filters = array(

        'PaymentDate'      =>  new PartialMatchFilter('PaymentDate'),
        'ChequePostedDate'      =>  new PartialMatchFilter('ChequePostedDate'),


    );

    parent::__construct($modelClass, $fields, $filters);
}

public function getQuery($searchParams, $sort = false, $limit = false, $existingQuery = null) {

    $dataList = parent::getQuery($searchParams, $sort, $limit, $existingQuery);

    $params = is_object($searchParams) ? $searchParams->getVars() : $searchParams;

    $query = $dataList->dataQuery();

    if(!is_object($searchParams)) {
        if (isset($params['PaymentDate'])&& $params['ChequePostedDate'] ) {
            $query->where('`PaymentNote`.PaymentDate BETWEEN \''.$params['PaymentDate'].' \' AND \''.$params['ChequePostedDate'].'\'');
        }
    }
    return $dataList->setDataQuery($query);
}
```

}

Comment: can you please give the details of... 1) PaymentNote DataObject, 2) some data from within the table and 3) the output of  $query->sql( ); just before the return in getQuery

Comment: i have added the full code. result says no data. but it has data within the selected time period

Comment: sorry that is only 1 of the 3 things I asked for... without knowing the structure of the dataobject, data in the db and the sql that is created it's not something I can help to debug

Comment: private static $db = array(
  'Status'   => "Enum('Pending,Failed,Completed,Aborted','Pending')",
  'Type'    => "Enum('New,Renewal','New')",
        'PaymentMethod'  => "Enum('Cash,Card,ChequeDeposit,ChequePost,Wire,Fund,PackageDiscount','Cash')",
  'Currency'   => 'Varchar(255)',
  'Amount'   => 'Decimal(10,2)',
  'PaymentDate'  => 'SS_Datetime','ChequePostedDate' => 'Date',

 );

Comment: @user3358839 Id suggest that you read https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/security/secure_coding/ the about escaping correctly . Note: I didn't exactly count the quotes you are using in the where :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `WithinRangeFilter` something like the following, but you need to use the `setMin()`, `setMax()` methods as per this forum response: https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/form-questions/show/11685

```
public function getQuery($searchParams, $sort = false, $limit = false, $existingQuery = null) {

    $dataList = parent::getQuery($searchParams, $sort, $limit, $existingQuery);
    $params = is_object($searchParams) ? $searchParams->getVars() : $searchParams;
    $query = $dataList->dataQuery();

    if(!is_object($searchParams)) {
        if (!empty($params['PaymentDate'] && !empty($params['ChequePostedDate'])) {
            return $dataList->filter('PaymentDate:WithinRange', [$params['PaymentDate'], $params['ChequePostedDate']]);
        }
    }

    return $dataList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it..
simply remove $filters

```
$filters = array(

   // 'PaymentDate'      =>  new PartialMatchFilter('PaymentDate'),
    //'ChequePostedDate'      =>  new PartialMatchFilter('ChequePostedDate'),


);
```

then it works